# Generating a range with irregular steps. Optimized

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, logarithm

Does PHP have existing functionality for irregular step ranges, is there a common solution to provide this functionality, or how can the following function be optimized?

The first function is the function I am concerned about.  The second function is a real world use case that generates an array to populate values for a function that outputs a select dropdown for HTML.

```
<?php

function range_multistep($min, $max, Array $steps, $jmp = 10) {
    $steps = array_unique($steps);
    sort($steps, SORT_NUMERIC);

    $bigstep = ($jmp > 0) ? $jmp : $jmp * -1;

    $e = ($min > 0) ? floor(log($min, $bigstep)) : 0;
    for (; ; $e++) {
        foreach ($steps as $step) {
            $jump = pow($bigstep, $e);
            $num = $step * $jump;
            if ($num > $max) {
                break 2;
            } elseif ($num >= $min) {
                $arr[] = $num;
            }
        }
    }

    $arr = array_unique($arr);
    sort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);

    return $arr;
}

function prices() {
    $price_steps = range_multistep(50, 100000, array(5, 10, 25));

    $prev_step = 0;
    foreach ($price_steps as $price) {
        $price_str = '$' . $prev_step . ' - $' . ($price - 1);
        $price_arr[] = $price_str;
        $prev_step = $price;
    }
    $price_arr[] = '$' . end($price_steps) . "+";

    return $price_arr;
}

print_r(prices());
```

The result of the previous:

```
Array
(
    [0] => $0 - $49
    [1] => $50 - $99
    [2] => $100 - $249
    [3] => $250 - $499
    [4] => $500 - $999
    [5] => $1000 - $2499
    [6] => $2500 - $4999
    [7] => $5000 - $9999
    [8] => $10000 - $24999
    [9] => $25000 - $49999
    [10] => $50000 - $99999
    [11] => $100000+
)
```

Comment: One thing to ponder, would it be better to generate a range based on min/max and run that array through a foreach over a while/for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$e` incrementor in the  `for` loop is more of a `while(1)` endless loop.

So instead misusing the incrementor in `pow()`, do the `pow` on your own by just multiplying once per iteration. Calling `pow()` can be pretty expensive, so doing the `pow` calculation your own would better distribute the multiplication onto each iteration.

**Edit:** The following is a variant of your function that distributes the `pow()` calculation over the iteration. Additionally it does more proper variable initialisation (the return value was not set for example), gives notice if `$min` and `$max` are swapped and corrects that, uses `abs` instead of your ternary, throws an exception if an invalid value was given for `log()`, renamed some variables and add `$num` to the return value as key first to spare the `array_unique` operation at the end:

```
/**
 * @param int $min
 * @param int $max
 * @param array $steps
 * @param int $jmp
 * @return array range
 */
function range_multistep($min, $max, Array $steps, $jmp = 10) {
    $range = array();
    if (!$steps) return $range;

    if ($min < $max) {
       trigger_error(__FUNCTION__.'(): Minima and Maxima mal-aligned.', E_USER_NOTICE);
       list($max, $min) = array($min, $max);
    }

    $steps = array_unique($steps);
    sort($steps, SORT_NUMERIC);

    $bigstep = abs($jmp);
    if ($bigstep === 0) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Value %d is invalid for jmp', $jmp));
    }

    $initExponent = ($min > 0) ? floor(log($min, $bigstep)) : 0;

    for ($multiplier = pow($bigstep, $initExponent); ; $multiplier *= $bigstep) {
        foreach ($steps as $step) {
            $num = $step * $multiplier;
            if ($num  > $max) {
                break 2;
            } elseif ($num >= $min) {
                $range[$num] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    $range = array_keys($range);
    sort($range, SORT_NUMERIC);

    return $range;
}
```

In case you feel experimental, it's also possible to turn the two loops (`for`+`foreach`) into one, but the readability of the code does not benefit from it:

```
for(
    $multiplier = pow($bigstep, $initExponent),
    $step = reset($steps)
        ;
    $num = $step * $multiplier,
    $num <= $max
        ;
    # infinite array iterator:
    ($step=next($steps))?:
    (
      $step=reset($steps)
      # with reset expression:
      AND $multiplier *= $bigstep
    )
){
    if ($num >= $min)
        $range[$num] = 1;
}
```

I think if you take care to not re-use variables (like the function parameter) and give them better to read names, improvement comes on it's own.

Comment: `$jmp` and `$jump` are two confusing, yet separate variables.  Is `$min != min($min, $max)` better than `$min < $max`?  If so, why?

Comment: Not really ;), now as you ask, I would choose `$min < $max` ;) - I did that part quickly at the end and was trying something else as well so just an artefact. I fully removed `$jump` as well, will check the wording of the answer, that's a mistake of mine.

Comment: Also, the typecast Array in the parameters, would that not trigger an error or give us an array which would make us never execute code behind `if (!$steps)`.  Maybe `if (empty($steps))` would be more suitable.

Comment: It's not a *typecast* it's just a type hint. PHP will thrown an exception if you pass anything else than an array to the function for that parameter. Next to that if it is empty, it is FALSE, so `!$steps` is just a short version for empty array in this case (array with no elements is boolean FALSE in PHP). It will return an empty range then which is the same as in the original function but just as a short-cut (early exit).

Comment: It's not boolean false, that's what raised my concern.  It is a falsy value though, I kind of expected an empty array to be true for some reason.  I guess it's because it's relatively different than the gist behind `0`, `""`, `null`, and `false`.

Comment: Sure it's not a boolean when passed to the function, and it's not either in there. But as `empty` is the opposite of boolean false (with an addition of `isset`), and `arrays` with no values evaluate to `FALSE` when operated boolean `!`, it's possible. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 2):

Repeated addition is best replaced by multiplication, and repeated multiplication is best replaced by raising to powers -- which you've done.

I see nothing here that requires improvement assuming you don't need "bulletproof" behavior in the face of `$jmp = 1` or `$min >= $max` badly-behaved inputs.

Comment: bulletproof isn't necessary, but it would be nice to make it feel complete.